# iFrame is not fixing correctly in android device

Tags: javascript, html, css, android-layout, iframe

i made a android app using it's web view. there contain a lot of functions. payment  integration etc. i integrate this payment method using a third party tool. This tool provide an external html page. when i load this page directly in to my web view it's work nicely.
but after i got a requirement that there need a back button in the payment page. after then i add this page using an IFRAME. after there is number of issues came related to the design. the content is not fitting in the IFRAME also there is not displaying the scroll bars.

i tried differant kind of javascript method but no output.
  If any solution present for this

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to the iframe scrolling problem**

1.**Zoom in** until the iframe portion of the page completely fills the screen.
  Tes might activiate the scrollbar and allow you to scroll the iframe.

2.Try **double-touching** the screen.  This means you use two fingers to scroll on the iframe area.

3.If neither #1 or #2 work, try a **different browser** such as Dolphin, xScope, or Opera.

If none of those three work, try out **Firefox**.  I listed Firefox separately and last because it is slow and resource-intensive on Android, but if it's your only recourse, then use it only when you must.

Can you provide more information on the content not fitting inside the iframe?

Comment: in my iframe i set width as 100%. basically i check this page in samsung galexy tab. This contain 480px width. but iframe is not fitting in 480px and there present a scolling in left side